# Finding Modules in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

I'm trying to find the module that fires a the feedback form on this website: https://apex4d.com/ but can't find it. In the code I see: `<jdoc:include type="modules" style="xhtml" name="feedback" />` but I have no idea where to find this module. I looked in the modules folder and I assumed there would be a folder called mod_feedback but there isn't.

I don't want to find it in the admin area (or perhaps I do, is this where I'm going wrong), I need to find it in the code.

Thanks

Comment: Is it maybe a admin modul? Per default is the view on site.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but how would I change that?

Comment: under the modul setting top-left is a drop down. Default is Site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In joomla each module have own position, and this code

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" style="xhtml" name="feedback" />
```

will display all modules with 'feedback' position. Not module type or name.

To check what module are assigned to this position you need to go into Administrator panel, and then into Extensions > Modules.

From this page you can filter all modules by 'feedback' position (just click 'Search tools' button.

After filtering in one of column you can find module type eg TypeName.

With this name you can check modules directory and try to find mod_TypeName